# Google Api Vision, "before_request" error

Tags: python, api

So I'm trying to use Google's vision api, where it takes recognizes the labeles,facial, and text detections....etc

But it unfortunately, I can't fix an error that's causing us to fall behind .

**SOURCE CODE**

```
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
from google.cloud import storage

def getCredentials():
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
            'eyeHear-cad56858f9be.json')
    return storage_client
    # buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    # print(buckets)

def instantiateClient():
    # Instantiates a client
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(
        credentials=getCredentials())

    # The name of the image file to annotate
    file_name = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'images/demo-image.jpg')

    # Loads the image into memory
    with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = types.Image(content=content)

    # Performs label detection on the image file
    response = client.label_detection(image=image)
    # labels = response.label_annotations

    # print('Labels:')
    # for label in labels:
    #     print(label.description)
```

It says "Client" object has no attribute, "before_request"

That's where I'm stuck, and I'm not sure what to do from there.

**ERROR**

```
ERROR:root:AuthMetadataPluginCallback "<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at 0x104746ef0>" raised exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py", line 77, in _call_
    callback_state, callback))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 77, in _call_
    callback(self._get_authorization_headers(context), None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 61, in _get_authorization_headers
    self._credentials.before_request(
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'before_request'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 54, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 487, in _call_
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 437, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: 'Client' object has no attribute 'before_request')>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testAPI.py", line 43, in <module>
    run_quickstart()
  File "testAPI.py", line 33, in run_quickstart
    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/vision_helpers/decorators.py", line 110, in inner
    return self.annotate_image(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/vision_helpers/__init__.py", line 67, in annotate_image
    r = self.batch_annotate_images([request], retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/vision_v1/gapic/image_annotator_client.py", line 158, in batch_annotate_images
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 139, in _call_
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 56, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: 'Client' object has no attribute 'before_request'
```

Comment: If in instantiateClient, you just return client and comment out the image loading code, does the client actually authenticate against the API? Seems like that's the root of it, if I had to guess.

Comment: What do you mean? can you explain more xd

Comment: Threw it in a partial answer below

Answer (score 1):

Strange, I got it running. I had to declare the path to my credentials directly in the call to os.environ. Maybe give that a try rather than using the from storage method?

```
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/Users/jeff/Downloads/test_client.json"

# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'collie.jpg')

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)

# Performs label detection on the image file
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations

print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

Output was:

```
dog
dog breed
dog like mammal
dog breed group
border collie
karelian bear dog
snout
native american indian dog
icelandic sheepdog
canadian eskimo dog
```

Input was

```
wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/Border_Collie_liver_portrait.jpg/220px-Border_Collie_liver_portrait.jpg
```

then rename to collie.jpg

Comment: It doesn't give an error but when I run it, nothing happens, because the image isn't linked in the "instantiateClient method"

Comment: Updated my answer - try changing your auth strategy with the os.environ thing